# What is the cardinality of this given set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb{R_{\ge 0}} \times \mathbb{R_{\ge 0}} \mid a + b = 1\}$. What is the cardinality of $A$? Is it countable or uncountable?

Comment: You should draw the graph. Then the answer should be plainly visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncountable; $a$ can be anything between $0$ and $1$, and then $b=1-a$ is still in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$, so $|A|\ge |[0,1]|$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You know that the set $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Is it true that for each $x\in[0,1]$ there is a $y\in[0,1]$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in A$?